# Array in JAVA., repeat?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a function using java language that takes in a 1D array and the size of the array as inputs to the function. I want to find out how many function values of are in the array. How would I do this?

Comment: One option, which doesn't require the use of any data structures other than an array, would be to first _sort_ the array, and second to walk through the array, incrementing a counter every time you hit a new value.

Comment: Another option, if you _can_ use more exotic data structures, would be to use a map and walk through the array once, inserting the same value for each number.  Then you can simply check the _number_ of keys in your map, which is the number of distinct values.

Comment: Why did you edit the question so that no one can see what it was?

Comment: Please keep the question as it is. It may be useful for other programmers as refeerence

Comment: Why did you remove the content of your question?  That is NOT how this site works.  You should leave your original question there so this can be part of the Stack Overflow repository of information from previously asked and answered questions.  If you don't want to restore the content of your question, then we will need to delete it as it is worthless as is since there's no question any more.  In the future, you can indicate to the community that your question has been answered by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer that was posted.  That also earns you reputation points.

Comment: I have flagged this for moderator attention.  The question needs to either be rolled back to the prior version that shows the actual content of the question or it needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1(**O(nlogn)**):

1. Sort the array.
2. Compare the adjacent elements in array
3. Increment the count whenever the adjacent elements are unequal. Please take care of three consecutive same elements using an extra variable.

Approach 2(**O(n)** but space complexity of **O(n)**):

1. Create a Hash Table for  value.
2. Insert a value if not present in the hash table.
3. Count and print the values for present in hashtable

Comment: A hash is too complex. I'd create a binary tree with left nodes having smaller values, right nodes having larger values. No need to deal with hash collisions; manageable space and time requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Find unique items from array:
1. Create one new array
2. Take each item from existing array
3. Check if the item is exist in new array
4. **If not exist push the item into new array** else go for next item
5. After iterating all item in array get the length of new array
```

Comment: How would we check to see if an item from existing array is in the new array?

Comment: Straight forward is, get each item from new array and compare it with current item in existing array.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n[10]  = {1,2,5,5,3,4,1,4,5,11};
    int count = 0; int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        int j;
            for (j=0; j<i; j++)
                if (n[i] == n[j])
                break;
            if (i == j)
                count += 1;
    }

     printf("The counts are: %d distinct elements", count);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yep, I used the another method.